# Shift left/right adding zeroes/ones and dropping first bits

Tags: c++, binary, shift

I've got to program a function that receives

- a binary number like `10001`, and
- a decimal number that indicates how many shifts I should perform.

The problem is that if I use the C++ operator `<<`, the zeroes are pushed from behind but the first numbers aren't dropped... For example

> shifLeftAddingZeroes(10001,1)

returns `100010` instead of `00010` that is what I want.

I hope I've made myself clear =P

Comment: Your numbers should always have 5 bits?

Comment: No, they can have a random amount of bits.

Comment: So where does the number representation "stop"? At the most significant "1"?

Comment: Well, from looking at the question, it appears the OP wants to retain the same number of digits as the input.

Comment: does the highest *lit* bit indicate the number of bits you want to *keep* ?

Comment: What have you tried? (Also, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve where you think shifting bits is the solution?)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are storing that information in int. Take into consideration, that this number actually has more leading zeroes than what you see, ergo your number is most likely 16 bits, meaning `00000000 00000001` . Maybe try AND-ing it with number having as many 1 as the number you want to have after shifting? (Assuming you want to stick to bitwise operations).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to bit shift and then limit the number of output bits which can be active (hold a value of 1). One way to do this is to create a mask for the number of bits you want, then AND the bitshifted value with that mask. Below is a code sample for doing that, just replace int_type with the type of value your using -- or make it a template type.

```
int_type shiftLeftLimitingBitSize(int_type value, int numshift, int_type numbits=some_default) {
    int_type mask = 0;
    for (unsigned int bit=0; bit < numbits; bit++) {
        mask += 1 << bit;
    }
    return (value << numshift) & mask;
}
```

Your output for `10001,1` would now be `shiftLeftLimitingBitSize(0b10001, 1, 5) == 0b00010`.

Realize that unless your numbits is exactly the length of your integer type, you will always have excess 0 bits on the 'front' of your number.